# Address Sanitizer Heap buffer Overflow

Tags: c++, while-loop, buffer-overflow

I was trying to solve this problem on leet code it works fine on my vs code and gcc compiler but i'm getting this
`Runtime error: Address sanitizer Heap buffer Overflow` error message with a long list of address or something on the website. Help me fix it. Here's the code

```
class Solution
{
public:
    char nextGreatestLetter(vector<char> v, char a)
    {
        int l=v.size()-1;
        if (v[l] < a)
        {
            return v[0];
        }
        int i = 0;
        while (v[i] <= a)
        {
            i++;
        }
        return v[i];
    }
};
```

p.s the array is sorted in ascending order

Comment: `int l=v.size()-1;` is an adventure if `v.size()` is 0.

Comment: What if all the characters in v are <= a?

Comment: Side note: Pass `v` by `const` reference. Probably be a lot less copying overhead.

Comment: Side note; When compiling on your computer, turn on the same sanitizers the judge is using. You'll get fewer surprises.

Comment: @user4581301 *Pass v by const reference.* False. It will prevent moving arg by a caller.

Comment: Side note: When it comes to improving programmer productivity almost nothing beats the debugger. Basic usage is to run the program in the debugger, step through the function in question line by line, and keep an eye out for the unexpected, like storing the wrong value or taking the wrong path. The unexpected is a bug in your code or your expectations and you need to fix either one before continuing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code snippet has a lot of problems:

- The while loop isn't guaranteed to terminate. If the last character of v is == a, then the first v[l] < a test will be false, but v[i] <= a might be true all the way through the array (it looks like v is meant to be pre-sorted into ascending order), which will have you eventually accessing v[i] for a value of i >= v.size().  That is an illegal/undefined array access and might be the source of the error message you report, if the test platform had strict bounds-checking enabled.
- The logic of returning v[0] if a is greater than any character in v (again, inferring from the loop that v is supposed to be pre-sorted into ascending order) also seems flawed.  Why not return the value of a instead?  The caller can easily see that if the return value was <= a, then there clearly was no element of v greater than a.
- It's almost certainly worth your time to handle cases where the passed-in v array is empty (v.size() == 0) or not actually pre-sorted, i.e. by caching n = v.size() and changing the loop condition to while (i < n && v[i] <= a).  Don't let fragile functions creep into your codebase!